# Error in airflow installation. Failed at building wheel for google-re2 & greenlet (setup.py)

Tags: python, airflow

When I follow the official documentation from Apache Airflow to pip3 install Airflow using the constraints file:
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start.html

I got the error message. The main part of the error message is:

```
> Building wheels for collected packages: google-re2, pendulum, greenlet
> Building wheel for google-re2 (setup.py) ... error   error:
> subprocess-exited-with-error
>      × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.   │ exit code: 1   ╰─> [15 lines of output]
>       running bdist_wheel
>       running build
>       running build_py
>       creating build
>       creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39
>       copying re2.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39
>       running build_ext
>       building '_re2' extension
>       creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39
>       clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Users/yuenfannie/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64
> -I/Users/yuenfannie/opt/anaconda3/include -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Users/yuenfannie/opt/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64
> -I/Users/yuenfannie/opt/anaconda3/include/python3.9 -c _re2.cc -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-39/_re2.o -fvisibility=hidden
>       clang: error: unable to read SDK settings for '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk'
>       clang: error: unable to read SDK settings for '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk'
>       sh: line 1:   848 Bus error: 10           /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -sdk
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk
> -find clang 2> /dev/null
>       clang: error: unable to find utility "clang", not a developer tool or in PATH
>       error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 72
>       [end of output]
>      note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.   ERROR: Failed building wheel for google-re2
```

Is there anything to be done with **setup.py** or **bdist_wheel**? What should be done in this case?
Any comments are welcome.

Answer (score 4):

Try to install 2.6.1. You'll also likely have pydantic issues too and can pip install 1.10.12. This worked for me in the past few days.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: it works well enough.

Answer (score 2):

Same issue here. I have solved by downgrading the version of airflow I was trying to install:

```bash
pip install "apache-airflow[celery]==2.6.1" --constraint "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-2.6.1/constraints-3.7.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

[Re-installing conda seems to be helping many people](https://github.com/apache/airflow/discussions/32852#discussioncomment-6547402)